# How to read a asp.net page with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, asp.net, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some data from a webpage using beautiful soup.

I am running into problems when I try to get convert the HTML document into a beautifulsoup object.

when I run the code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
```

The error message im getting is :

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xa9' in file      C:/Users/mlee/PycharmProjects/BsTest/htmlparse.py on line 683, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

I believe this is because there are some asp.net viewstate objects in the html which are base64 encoded.

Is there a suggested workaround to this or will I have to use a different tool?

Also, I am primarily just interested in getting the javascript generated portions of text. Is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this header

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

on the first line of your `htmlparse.py` file, make sure that PyCharm saves the file as utf-8 encoded.

This has nothing to do with asp/viewstate. You have utf characters in the file.

> I am primarily just interested in getting the javascript generated portions of text. Is there a better way of doing this?

You might want to use [Selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) + python bindings for doing the task. Another option is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: ah thank you, that was the solution. It turns out the get_text() method doesn't return the text generated by the javascript correctly. Conceptually, what needs to happen to retrieve the text generated by the javascript and is beautifulsoup capable of doing this? Cheers

Comment: @JesterKynes BeautifulSoup doesn't execute Javascript as far as I know. You need to look into libraries which execute Javacript or use some headless browser engine with bindings to python. Check out PhantomJS, CasperJS and Selenium.